# Swift Json Single Quote Parse

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder, single-quotes

I have a problem while parsing json which includes single quote. I am using `JSONDecoder`. I added response from API at below and I don't want to do any replacement or some regex operations. Are there any workaround for that?

```
"{\'value1\': true, \'value2\':\'2021-02-08\'}"
```

Comment: No there is no workaround

Comment: 'JSON' with single quotes is not JSON. *I don't want to do any replacement...* then you cannot deserialize it with one of the standard APIs, period.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is simply not valid JSON. Since it's not valid JSON there's no way to configure `JSONDecoder` to decode it.

If you aren't in charge of the service that outputs that string, the only thing you can do to use it with `JSONDecoder` is to modify the string to become valid JSON by, as you suggested, doing text replacement.